# Rails 3.1.3 using anchor attribute with link_to tag from posts/index to posts/show/id not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, link-to, rails-3.1

I am using a link_to tag on my posts/index view and want to link it to my posts/show/id view with an anchor that makes it scroll down to the comments form. For some reason I can't get the anchor to work. Here is my code:

**In posts/index**

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Comment', post, :anchor => 'comment_form' %>
```

This fails to append the # sign to the end of the link, so it is just localhost:3000/posts/id.
I have also tried many variations for link_to, including:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Comment', post(:anchor => 'comment_form' %>
```

**and**

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Comment', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => @post, :anchor => 'comment_form' %>
```

but I've had no luck.

Here is my posts#show action:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

and here is the posts/show view where I want the anchor to scroll to:

```
<h2><a name="comment_form" id="comment_form">Add a comment:</a></h2>
```

Furthermore, any of the above works if I am linking to something on the index page, as I can see the hash # has been appended to the outputted url. For some reason it is not working when trying to link to the show page. Any help with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
link_to('Add a comment', post_path(post, :anchor => 'comment_form'))
```

The second argument to `link_to` is typically passed as-is to `url_for`, and the third argument is used as an attributes hash for the `<a>` element that ultimately gets generated.

So in your first example, you're passing a `Post` object as the second argument and a hash as the third argument. Only the `Post` would be passed to `url_for`. It never sees the hash containing the `:anchor` option, so you wouldn't see the anchor at the end of the generated URL. (But you would probably see an `anchor="comment_form"` attribute on the generated `<a>` element.)

Your second example is syntactically incorrect. I imagine that resulted in an error.

Your third example...should've worked. I'm not sure why it didn't :-)