# Is it possible to use a string containing the character "/" in a url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I have a model (Category) with a `:name` attribute, and I defined a route for it like this:

```
get ':name' => 'categories#show'
```

The problem is, some Categories have names containing the character "/". So if, for example, a Category is named "Drugs/Pharmacy", then the url is interpreted as `categories#Drugs#Pharmacy`, not `categories#Drugs/Pharmacy`.

Has anyone else ran into this problem? How could I get around this? I suppose I could slice that character from every url, but it would be cool if I could include it somehow.

Comment: Are you ok if you get like `categories#Drugs_Pharmacy` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I guess that's one solution. Would that be easy to accomplish?

Comment: Pass name value like I said from the place you are calling this _url_...

Comment: try this `get ':name' => 'categories#show', :constraints => { :name => /[\/a-z]+/i }`..........

Comment: How are you getting *anchor*.. I have no idea?

Comment: @ArupRakshit What do you mean by "anchor"?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251606/rails-3-1-3-using-anchor-attribute-with-link-to-tag-from-posts-index-to-posts-sh